# Triggering a custom event buried inside a function but bound to 'window'

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I thought I would be able to dispatch the `test` event by doing `window.dispatchEvent(test)`.  In fact, if I change the event listener from `test` to `click`, it fires the alert.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var functionName = function () {
    function functionName() {

        // bind method
        this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);

        this.setupListeners();
    }

    functionName.prototype.setupListeners = function setupListeners() {
        window.addEventListener('test', this.doSomething);
    };

    functionName.prototype.doSomething = function doSomething(event) {
        alert('Hello!');
    };

    return functionName;

}();
```

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-custom-events/    this might be helpful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the `event` object like this:

```
var event = new Event('test');

// Dispatch the event.
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

See the working snippet:

```js
var functionName = function() {
  function functionName() {

    // bind method
    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);

    this.setupListeners();
  }

  functionName.prototype.setupListeners = function setupListeners() {
    window.addEventListener('test', this.doSomething);
  };

  functionName.prototype.doSomething = function doSomething(event) {
    alert('Hello!');
  };

  return functionName;

}();

var myfun = new functionName();

var event = new Event('test');

// Dispatch the event.
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```